# Unable to read data from the transport connection - TFS Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am having an issue regarding Team Foundation Server where i am getting the error 'Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.' whenever i try to check in a project. I also get this error from time to time when i try to 'Get Latest Version'. I have attempted to use TFS in both Visual Studio 2010 & Visual Studio 2013 but i get the same issue.

I have also tried the following:

- Remapping my TFS Source Control
- Deleting all files from the local path of my source control and redownloading
- Turned my firewalls off
- Switching the port in which my Ethernet cable is connected to

I have included a screenshot of this error below:

[image: Error Message]

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this, i would be massively grateful!

Comment: This error is indicative of a network issue. Visual Studio makes many small calls on a Get, but larger calls on a CheckIn. Sounds like your network is dodgy. Have you tries a different switch, or vlan?

Comment: @MrHinsh I have tried a different switch, can you think of anything else? :)

Comment: As @s-krishna mentions, IIS will kill very slow connections. It's a common problem that will be even more common with certain VPNs and Network Security Appliances on your network as well.

Answer (score 4):

I came across [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylaf/archive/2010/02/10/team-foundation-server-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host.aspx) which talks about this exact same problem. The author of the article talks about this error being related to http.sys bug.

Below is an excerpt from that article

> Http.sys is the http protocol stack that IIS uses to perform http
>   communication with clients.  It has a timer called MinBytesPerSecond
>   that is responsible for killing a connection if its transfer rate
>   drops below some kb/sec threshold.  By default, that threshold is set
>   to 240 kb/sec.  It turns out that there is a bug with this timer and
>   it is causing connections to be prematurely killed. We have found that lowering this threshold reduces the number of connections that are killed by the server.

See if that helps?

**Note**: As mentioned in the article, the hotfix and settings have to be changed in the Application Tier (AT). TFS consists of a Application tier and a Database Tier. If your unfamiliar with the term, then you probably have just a single server installation, which means both the AT and DT are on the same server.

Comment: @s-krishna I have followed that link and it does seem to be what i'm looking for. However, when i download and run the hotfix i found by following that link it says it is not applicable for my system, do you have any ideas? Just for your information i am running Windows 7 64-bit. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CharlieStuart I believe you should be installing the fix on the server and not on your laptop/desktop

Comment: @s-krishna We're using Microsoft's Visual Studio Online so we're not hosting our own TFS therefore there is no server machine to install the fix to. Apologies if i did not make that clear. Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: @CharlieStuart TFS is very chatty and given that you are using this over the Internet puts network back into the equation. What is your network speed? Are you facing the problem only for a large file or irrespective of file-size ?

Comment: @s-krishna It seems as if it occurs when it is a larger file but my network connection is currently 20Mbps which seems fine. I have also tried turning off things like firewalls, anti-vrius, etc just encase they were somehow blocking the connection

Comment: @CharlieStuart Could it possibly your bandwidth with the MS VisualStudio online account? (Upload/Download Limit)? I dont have one and am not sure if something similar is measured / limited. You might want to check that. This might be an option if the requests are given lower priority due to used up bandwidth and the remaining requests are probably only served on best-effort-basis ?

Comment: @s-krishna Unfortunately i don't think its anything to do with the server itself as my colleagues are using it and their TFS functions absolutely fine, maybe its something more specific to my machine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83111/discussion-between-s-krishna-and-charlie-stuart).